# how to print facebook reviews

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have created a page with this code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook/src/Facebook/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$config = array();
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'myappid',
  'app_secret' => 'myappsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  'default_access_token' => 'myaccesstoken', // optional

  ]);
      $page_id='mypageid';
      $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$page_id.'/');
    // Send the request to Graph

/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    'mypageid/ratings?fields=open_graph_story&access_token=myaccesstoken'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}


$graphEdge = $request->getGraphEdge();
```

If I print with echo graphEdge results are: https://allevamentochihuahua.com/recensioni.php

How can print all reviews in a table?

I've try to print an array but not work...

```
foreach ($graphEdge as $reviews) {
  echo "<ul>\n<li>" . $contact['review_text'] . " : " . $review['value'] . "</li></ul>\n";
}
```

But not work.. also I need insert a name of user that review my page, but I don't find in grapEdge..

Can you help me?